# How to write a node to communicate with USB?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS I want to communicate with robot base which receives data through USB. So I want to write a ROS node that can write data on USB port.
Please help me.
**can some one provide me python or C++ code for opening USB port, initializing it and to send the data on the port?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67508/how-to-write-a-node-to-communicate-with-usb?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-07-30**:
Check the source of ROS serial? http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What kind of usb device and robot base is it? You could look at ROS serial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-17**:
It is FTDI device. means the base is having a microcontroller based circuit for motor control. the microcontroller can actually handle RS-232 and the FTDI device converts RS-232 data in to packets of USB to support the communication.
I just need to send specific data to USB port.